# JSON string giving NULL after deserialization iOS

Tags: ios, nsjsonserialization

Hello I have 2 `JSON` strings like this.

**1st object**

```
 {
   "LeaveEntryCode":0,
   "RequestId":0,
   "EmployeeCode":17186,
   "LeaveYear":2016,
   "LeaveTypeCode":1,
   "LeaveReasonCode":0,
   "BaseType":"ess",
   "StartDate":"2016-10-24T00:00:00",
   "EndDate":"2016-10-24T00:00:00",
   "NoOfDays":1.0,
   "StartDateSession":"full",
   "EndDateSession":"full",
   "PreApproved":false,
   "ForDate":"1901-01-01T00:00:00",
   "Remarks":"test from Android",
   "CoveringPersonCode":0,
   "AttachedDocument":"[{\"DocumentId\":354,\"DocumentName\":\"Screenshot_2016-04-15-00-35-11.png\",\"DocumentType\":\"image/png\"}]",
   "RequestStatus":"P",
   "Deleted":false,
   "Status":false,
   "CreatedBy":0,
   "CreatedDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00",
   "UpdatedBy":0,
   "UpdatedDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00",
   "DeletedBy":0,
   "DeletedDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00",
   "ModuleId":2,
   "ObjectId":20,
   "StartDateString":"10/24/2016",
   "EndDateString":"10/24/2016",
   "LeaveDayList":[
      "10/24/2016-FH,10/24/2016-SH"
   ],
   "SystemLeaveTypeCode":"ANN",
   "LeaveTypeName":"ANNUAL",
   "Employee":null,
   "LieuDayList":null,
   "BaseLeaveType":"ANN",
   "CoveringPersonName":null,
   "LeaveReasonName":"test",
   "DocumentSource":"LEAVE"
}
```

**2nd object**

```
{
   "LeaveEntryCode":0,
   "RequestId":0,
   "EmployeeCode":17227,
   "LeaveYear":2016,
   "LeaveTypeCode":1,
   "LeaveReasonCode":3,
   "BaseType":"ess",
   "StartDate":"2016-10-26T00:00:00",
   "EndDate":"2016-10-27T00:00:00",
   "NoOfDays":2.0,
   "StartDateSession":"full",
   "EndDateSession":"half",
   "PreApproved":false,
   "ForDate":"1901-01-01T00:00:00",
   "Remarks":"Test attachments in things to do",
   "CoveringPersonCode":0,
   "AttachedDocument":null,
   "RequestStatus":"P",
   "Deleted":false,
   "Status":false,
   "CreatedBy":0,
   "CreatedDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00",
   "UpdatedBy":0,
   "UpdatedDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00",
   "DeletedBy":0,
   "DeletedDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00",
   "ModuleId":2,
   "ObjectId":20,
   "StartDateString":"10/26/2016",
   "EndDateString":"10/27/2016",
   "LeaveDayList":[
      "10/26/2016-FH,10/26/2016-SH,10/27/2016-FH,10/27/2016-SH"
   ],
   "SystemLeaveTypeCode":"ANN",
   "LeaveTypeName":"ANNUAL",
   "Employee":null,
   "LieuDayList":null,
   "BaseLeaveType":"ANN",
   "CoveringPersonName":"",
   "LeaveReasonName":"test",
   "DocumentSource":"LEAVE",
   "AttachedDocument":"[{\"DocumentId\":352,\"DocumentName\":\"IMG_2322.JPG\",\"DocumentType\":\"JPG\"}]"
}
```

I want to get the `AttachedDocument` value into an array. So I did like this.

```
NSError *jsonError;
NSData *objectData = [[[[dm.mutArraySelectedReq objectAtIndex:index] objectForKey:@"RequestDetails"] valueForKey:@"RequestForm"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:objectData
                                                     options:0
                                                       error:&jsonError];

if (json!=NULL) {//AttachedDocument
    NSString *str=[json valueForKey:@"AttachedDocument"];
    NSData *data2=[str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSDictionary *json2 = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data2
                                                         options:0
                                                           error:&jsonError];
    if (json2!=NULL) {
        NSArray *arrayAttached=[NSArray arrayWithObject:json2];
        dm.mutArrayAttachedDocs=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:arrayAttached];
    }


}
```

My 1st object giving me the correct value for `str` variable. But 2nd object giving me  for `AttachedDocument` value

I am putting only the key value of that AttachedDocument

**1st object's**

```
"AttachedDocument": "[
{
\"DocumentId\":354,
\"DocumentName\":\"Screenshot_2016-04-15-00-35-11.png\",
\"DocumentType\":\"image/png\"
}
]"
```

**2nd object's**

```
"AttachedDocument":"[
{
\"DocumentId\":352,
\"DocumentName\":\"IMG_2322.JPG\",
\"DocumentType\":\"JPG\"
}
]"
```

Can you please explain me what is the differance (rather than image/png and JPG). Why my second object giving me null for `AttachedDocument`
Please help me.
Thanks

Comment: Format your JSON samples into different lines so its easier to see their structure.

Comment: FYI - do not use `valueForKey:` to get an object from an `NSDictionary`. Use `objectForKey:` unless you have a specific and clearly understood need to use key-value coding.

Comment: @rmaddyI used objectfor key to get my str but I am getting this error *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSNull dataUsingEncoding:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: Why are you storing attached document value in string? Directly you can store in array right?

Comment: in your second string there is two  `AttachedDocument `, where one of it is "AttachedDocument":null, fix this and try

Answer (score 0):

Yes 1 st object is valid JSON format.

But when we check the 2 object

```
{
    "LeaveEntryCode": 0,
    "RequestId": 0,
    "EmployeeCode": 17227,
    "LeaveYear": 2016,
    "LeaveTypeCode": 1,
    "LeaveReasonCode": 3,
    "BaseType": "ess",
    "StartDate": "2016-10-26T00:00:00",
    "EndDate": "2016-10-27T00:00:00",
    "NoOfDays": 2.0,
    "StartDateSession": "full",
    "EndDateSession": "half",
    "PreApproved": false,
    "ForDate": "1901-01-01T00:00:00",
    "Remarks": "Test attachments in things to do",
    "CoveringPersonCode": 0,
```

> "AttachedDocument": null,

```
    "RequestStatus": "P",
    "Deleted": false,
    "Status": false,
    "CreatedBy": 0,
    "CreatedDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
    "UpdatedBy": 0,
    "UpdatedDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
    "DeletedBy": 0,
    "DeletedDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
    "ModuleId": 2,
    "ObjectId": 20,
    "StartDateString": "10/26/2016",
    "EndDateString": "10/27/2016",
    "LeaveDayList": [
        "10/26/2016-FH,10/26/2016-SH,10/27/2016-FH,10/27/2016-SH"
    ],
    "SystemLeaveTypeCode": "ANN",
    "LeaveTypeName": "ANNUAL",
    "Employee": null,
    "LieuDayList": null,
    "BaseLeaveType": "ANN",
    "CoveringPersonName": "",
    "LeaveReasonName": "test",
    "DocumentSource": "LEAVE",
```

> "AttachedDocument":
>   "[{\"DocumentId\":352,\"DocumentName\":\"IMG_2322.JPG\",\"DocumentType\":\"JPG\"}]"

```
}
```

Two JSON objects have the same that's why 2nd object give NULL value when de-serialize it 
.